# Python Regular Expression query

Tags: python

I have this code example where I'm reading from a text file four different colors.

This is my **colors.txt**:

```
###
#####
#########

#example colors
#line of colors
#line colors PART 1
        color gray
        color blue


# line colors PART 2
        color yellow
        color green
```

Where's I'm getting `gray` and `blue` from `PART 1`, and `yellow` and `blue` from `PART 2`

My Python code for this example is:

```
#!/usr/lib/env python
import re

file = open("color.txt","r")
content = file.read()
file.close()
content = content.split('PART ')[1:]
dic = {}
for part in content:
    dic[int(part[0])] = part[1:] 


def color(part_index):
    color = re.findall('color\s(.*?)\s',dic[part_index] )
    return color

print color(1) #Colors of PART 1
print color(2)# Colors of PART 2
```

After runing this code I got this output:

> Part 1 : ['gray', 'blue']
>
> Part 2 : ['yellow', 'green']

I would like to print the colors by separated for example

`color(1)` as `gray`, `color(2)` as `blue` , `color(3)` as `yellow` and `color(4)` as `green`

That way my output would be:

> gray
>
> blue
>
> yellow
>
> green

Is there a possible way to do that? if so I'd be very grateful. Thank you Community.

Comment: If you don't want the output in multiple pieces, don't split `content` into multiple pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this list, and then use it in `color` instead of `dic`.

```
colors = [None] # Garbage value to preserve 1-based indexing
for value in dic.values():
    colors += value
```